# Moving Windows 10 software RAID to another machine

Tags: windows-10, software-raid

I have a quick question regarding the software RAID (0) tool built in Windows 10. I have an array consisting of 3 mechanical (SATA III) hard drives - it is used to process data, there are no system files on it. I would like to move this array to a new Windows 10 PC. If I just plugged in the drives into the new computer, would Windows see them as an already existing array? Or should I expect to loose all of the data? What would be the best approach to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: Solved. If anybody had the same concern - the array is instantly recognised by Windows 10 once connected to the new computer, no other configuration steps are necessary.

Comment: What exactly might you be referring to? Dynamic Disks?

Comment: Yes! Dynamic disks set to operate in RAID 0 using the Windows 10 disk manager.